# No output after running Python script in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I'm having an issue getting console outputs from my python scripts in Sublime Text 3. I have scoured Stackoverflow and cannot find a solution.

What I'm interested in doing is running a script within Sublime Text 3 using Command + B, and having the output appear in the console. If I run a simple Hello World script, the console disappears and the status bar says "Build Finished". I don't get any output saying "Finished in ___ s.", and the output is not printed when I re-open the console.

I know I'm not using "Python - Syntax Check" after pressing Command+Shift+B. In my settings, "show_panel_on_build": is true.

I know how to display the output using SublimeREPL, but I just want the output displayed in the console in ST3, and not in a separate tab or in Terminal.

I'm not sure what changed, but I never had this issue before, and I never had to define my own build system. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
>>> sublime.log_build_systems(True)
build: relevant build actions with scope source.python - [Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build#, Packages/Python/Python.sublime-build#Syntax Check]
build: building with previous choice
Running python3 -u "/Users/jfk/Documents/Code-Anki/Python/642_hwD4.py"
```

Comment: what is your Hello World script, btw? `print('Hello World')`?

Comment: @KeithHall Yes, that it what my script looks like. In general, it's not working for any of my scripts. I've updated the original post with the console output.